# Recommended way to find typos in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have developed a JavaScript file which I use in the context of a WordPress plugin. The jQuery contains a typo:

```
alert('prv_requestSelectionComplement check odds_pos for horse_id='+tmpSel.horse_id+' oddsPositionLimit='.JSON.stringify(oddsPositionLimit)+' odds_pos='+complement.odds_pos);
```

You see: Before `JSON` I used the PHP '.' instead of the JavaScript '+'.

I did not get any error nor warning. The function just stopped working. It took me a while to spot the problem with careful code review. Is there a possibility to get a reasonable error message without double checking all the places where I edited? For example using Firebug?

What is the recommended way to deal with this problem?

Comment: You can do try/catch and write out the error in console to find it

Comment: Three notes: JavaScript is not jQuery. And the code you've posted is pure JavaScript. And the reason why you didn't get an error is that `'string'.something` is valid JavaScript syntax (because strings are objects in JavaScript and have some properties and methods). Also, I suggest you use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, so you don't have to click away the modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try/Catch will help you:

```
try {
    alert(this is an error);
}
catch (e){
    console.log('There is a error: ' + e);
    alert('There is a error: ' + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you should get the following error within the Firebug or DevTools console:

> " oddsPositionLimit=".JSON is undefined

This message already indicates that the error is located between your string and your `JSON.stringify()` call.

Note that `'string'.something` is valid JavaScript syntax, because strings are objects in JavaScript and have some properties and values. So the error message does not refer to the dot between your string and `JSON` but says that the property `JSON` is not defined for the string `" oddsPositionLimit="`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought too: I should get an error in Firebug. However, I don't get this error in the console. Do I have to change some settings to activate error logging?

Comment: Error logging is on by default but can be turned off. See [*Console* panel options > *Show JavaScript Errors*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Options_Menu).